# User created chat rooms in Tigase

Tags: xmpp, chatroom, tigase

In Tigase, how a connected user can "creates chat rooms" which are visible to all the contacts in roster so that any of them can "join" the room (with creator’s permission)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such thing in the XMPP protocol specification, hence it is not available in the Tigase server. The simplest way to achieve something like this would be to create a chat room and put a link to the room in the presence status message. This message would be automatically visible to all contacts in the roster.
They could click on the link and join the room.

However, the main issue is whether the XMPP client you use understands XMPP links and can join room after the link is clicked.